# Angular reactive form hidden input not binding?

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form where I create the controls from my data model. Initially, everything is sorted by a datapoint called the "processingOrder" in numerical order.

Within my form array, I am using `*ngFor` to iterate over controls and store the index in a hidden `form control`. If I move a record up or down in my table, the index thats being applied to the hidden field should reflect the change in my model right?

```
<form [formGroup]="rulesForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
<div formGroupName="ruleData">
   <div formArrayName="rules">
      <div *ngFor="let child of rulesForm.controls.ruleData.controls.rules.controls; let i = index">
         <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Rule Name" formControlName="name"/> &nbsp; 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Rule Description" formControlName="description"/> &nbsp;
            <input type="text" placeholder="Processing Order" formControlName="processingOrder"/> &nbsp;
            <button class="button" (click)="move(-1, i)">Move Up</button> &nbsp; 
            <button class="button" (click)="move(1, i)">Move Down</button>


            <!-- Why doesn't this update my model when it gets a new index? -->
            <input type="hidden" formControlName="processingOrder" [value]="i">


         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would have expected that in my plunker, the processing order numbers should always remain in the 1-5 order and each time a rule is moved up or down, the model is updated to the new index it received.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCgHPEaUM00aLxM6Sf9t?p=preview

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`formControlName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) directive has [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#inputs) input which is bound to control's model and when changed from the code will update all its instances on view. So, just replace `[value]="i"` with `[ngModel]="i + 1"`:

```
<input type="hidden" formControlName="processingOrder" [ngModel]="i + 1">
```

binding to HTML input's property `value` (`[value]="i + 1"`) will update current input on the view but won't update control's model, thus won't affect another instances with the same control name.

You also can remove hidden input and place `[value]="i + 1"` on the text input:

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Processing Order" 
       [ngModel]="i + 1"
       formControlName="processingOrder"/>
```

please note that `processingOrder` value will always be overridden by `ngFor`'s index `i`

**2021 UPDATE :)**
be aware of `ngModel` (with reactive form directives) [deprecation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated) since NG6:

> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and is scheduled for removal in a future version of Angular.

Comment: This seems to be working well - Just having a small issue when I delete a rule from my object. If I have not moved any rules around prior to deleting, the rules continue to be in the correct order by index upon each removal. However, if I move a rule and then go delete one, the one the index at the location the record was removed seems to keep its old index.. I think? Ends up leaving 2 records in the object with the same processing order. Any thoughts on how that would happen?

Comment: I updated your plunker with 'Remove' button, seems to work properly. Please update my plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/NvSkiutOQLeu9i41H1AT?p=preview) so I can reproduce mentioned by you issue, then I will try to help

Comment: Thanks, looks like my issue is elsewhere. The `ngModel` solved my problem though. Wasn't aware it could be used with reactive forms.

Comment: Was glad to help you :).  As I already said, `ngModel` here it is just an '@input' for `formControlName` directive (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L90) and it belongs to `ReactiveFormsModule` (not `FormsModule`)

Comment: Some new problems with this solution: It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7

Comment: You are absolutely right, this was answered for Angular 5 I think

Comment: any update for angular 8? I need to use index of ngFor in a hidden field, but it seems to be deprecated

Comment: @Droa - please create a STACKBLITZ snapshot of your problem and I will try to help you

Comment: @Andriy, the ngModel is not "deprecation", the deprecation is using in **the same** tag formControl (or formControlName) and ngModel. (Really it should never have been used)

Comment: thanks @Eliseo for pointing out, I updated my update

Answer (score -2):

Add this to the bottom of the move up/down handling method,

```
move(shift, currentIndex) {
  const rules = this.rulesForm.get(['ruleData', 'rules']);

  let newIndex: number = currentIndex + shift;
  if(newIndex === -1) {
    newIndex = rules.length - 1;
  } else if(newIndex == rules.length) {
    newIndex = 0;
  }

  const currentGroup = rules.at(currentIndex);
  rules.removeAt(currentIndex);;
  rules.insert(newIndex, currentGroup)

  // logic to re-calculate processingOrder in the correct ascending order
  let i = 0;
  this.rulesForm.get(['ruleData', 'rules']).controls.forEach((elem) => {
    i++;
    elem.get('processingOrder').setValue(i);
  });
}
```

It basically re-assigns the processingOrder numbers in ascending order based on the formArray length. Hope it helps. (Confirmed it working in plunker)

You don't need the `hidden` `input` in the template for this to work. Also, if you specify more than one input controls (here input elements of type 'text' and 'hidden' for 'processingOrder') with the same `formControlName` then it probably is not gonna work as you expect in a reactive form.