# value attribute does not appear in Angular ngForm

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have a simple Angular ngForm I'm using for a put request. Because I need the id attribute to make the put request, I have attempted to add it in a hidden value. However, whenever the form is submitted the hidden id field is blank.

How can I pass in a pre-defined value to an input that will appear when the form is submitted?

I have tried multiple approaches, but nothing I have found online has worked. The hidden id field value is the one that won't appear.

The form I have is:

```
    <form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editTodoTest(editForm.value)">
      Todo<input type="text" name="description" ngModel /> UserId<input
        type="text"
        name="userId"
        ngModel
      />
      Completed<input type="text" name="completed" ngModel />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" ngModel />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: did you try `<input type="hidden">`?

Comment: yeah, hiding the input isn't the problem, it's getting the value attribute to appear.

Comment: please show your ts code

Comment: if you need to just have an attribute to send along the format while submitting why not just add it in your component class why create an input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478708/angular-reactive-form-hidden-input-not-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
   <form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editTodoTest(editForm.value)">
  Todo<input type="text" name="description" ngModel /> UserId<input
    type="text"
    name="userId"
    ngModel
  />
  Completed<input type="text" name="completed" ngModel />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" ngModel=10 />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[for STACKBLIZ example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyndzi)